# How can I copy&paste from the host to a KVM guest?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a QEMU/KVM virtual machine created with Virtual Machine Manager.

I would like to be able to copy text on the host and paste it into the guest, and the other way around too.

How can I share the clipboard between the host and the guest?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/virt-manager-copy-paste-functionality-to-the-vm

Comment: It's kinda of a DIY solution but I simply opened a port on my VM machine using netcat and whatever I send appears on my VM netcat listener.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just install the package spice-vdagent in the guest virtual machine:

```
sudo apt install spice-vdagent
```

The clipboard is automatically shared - we can copy and paste between the host and the guest.

Comment: Is there something similar to spice-vdagent for Windows guests (on Linux hosts)?

Comment: @BengtOlsson https://www.spice-space.org/download/binaries/spice-guest-tools/

Comment: sipmply you can connect with guest(kvm) through `ssh` and on the host's terminal you have clipboard available.

Comment: How to for windows?

Comment: @MUYBelgium For windows guest, try use [this](https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe). For more information, visit [here](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html) for the *Windows binaries* section.

Comment: does not work for me in cli

Comment: had to reboot guest to be able to make it work

Comment: I could not get it to work with this exact setup: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884534/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-qemu/1046792#1046792

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: Doesn't work on MacOS host.

Comment: It also needs to be started and enabled `systemctl start spice-vdagentd`  `systemctl enable spice-vdagentd`

Comment: Is `spice-vdagent` supposed to work with the client's CLI (without GUI) or not? I guess no, because the MAN page claims it's an " X11 session agent".

Answer (score 13):

For my **Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya** machine [*timelf123* provided the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858649/how-can-i-copypaste-from-the-host-to-a-kvm-guest/972310?noredirect=1#comment1435137_858650):

- In my Windows guest (Windows 7) downloaded and installed [**spice-guest-tools-latest.exe**](https://www.spice-space.org/download/binaries/spice-guest-tools/).
- **Before That**, back in my QEMU/KVM **Virtual Machine Manager** I had to switch the guest machine's display to **Spice**.
- **Before That**, back in my Linux host I had to fire up **Synaptic Package Manager** and install **gir1.2-spice-client-gtk-3.0**.

Comment: Sorry. It's all right here. "“timelf123's link” is a reference his (timelf123's) comment on the preceding answer. I see that's not clear. In hindsight perhaps I should have commented rather than answered.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I included the links directly to your answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7):

In case the question pops up - what if it's Ubuntu server or similar?

Don't run around in circles - install openssh-server on the vm, and when you ssh in you cut and paste into your favourite terminal.

Comment: although this might not directly answer the question, this is a viable option if you can reach the host via ssh from the network your favorite terminal is running from. It also seems that an X server needs to be running for the clipboard to work via SPICE if using virt-viewer but it should work with virt-manager with spice-vdagent installed.

Comment: That's "out of the box thinking", and although it doesn't answer the question directly, it's the best answer, if the guest is a Linux type machine. Previously the answer was downvoted, but I find that a bit harsh.

Answer (score 4):

In year 2021, qemu uses `qemu-vdagent` chardev for copy&paste, which turns off clipboard by default, so simply installing `spice-vdagent` package in guest OS does not work.

The solution of 2021 is:

1. Install `spice-vdagent` package as the current answer said,
2. Have qemu support spice (--enable-spice --enable-spice-protocol in `./configure` option),
3. Launch qemu using:

   ```
   qemu-system-x86_64 [ ... ] \
     -chardev qemu-vdagent,id=ch1,name=vdagent,clipboard=on \
     -device virtio-serial-pci \
     -device virtserialport,chardev=ch1,id=ch1,name=com.redhat.spice.0
   ```

   P.S. A side effect on my qemu is that the mouse moves more smoothly thanks to vdagent.

Reference: https://www.kraxel.org/blog/2021/05/qemu-cut-paste/

Comment: don't work for me.. invalid parameter 'clipboard'

Comment: Yeap invalid `clipboard` param. Is that because the spice isn't enabled?

Comment: I don't understand step 2 nor your reference mentions your step 2. Can you clirify?

Comment: @João Pimentel Ferreira: Thanks for asking. I built qemu myself from source. Step 2 of my answer mentions the building arguments for qemu to support spice. These arguments are written in a configuration file used by Makefile named `configure'. Because it is placed in the current folder, path "./" is specified. Details for configure scripts can be found here: https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html